# stats$height~stats$treatment, plant=="A")

Tags: r, anova

Thanks in advance for reading this message. I am new to r and trying to perform an anova on a subset within a subset of data which is below called stats.

```
treatment   plant   Climate height  
ODOD    OD  WW  26.4
ODOD    OD  WW  NA
ODOD    OD  WW  24.3
ODOD    OD  WW  19.5
ODOD    OD  D   13
ODOD    OD  D   19
ODOD    OD  D   33.4
ODOD    OD  D   17
KOD     K   WW  62.7
KOD     K   WW  78.7
KOD     K   WW  70
KOD     K   WW  65.6
KOD     K   D   54.8
KOD     K   D   51.6
KOD     K   D   57.4
KOD     K   D   59.6
BOD     B   WW  83.1
BOD     B   WW  80.2
BOD     B   WW  86.9
BOD     B   WW  62.4
BOD     B   D   36.5
BOD     B   D   30.5
BOD     B   D   43
BOD     B   D   49.5
IOD     I   WW  50.4
IOD     I   WW  NA
IOD     I   WW  46.9
IOD     I   WW  59.6
IOD     I   D   44.3
IOD     I   D   33.2
IOD     I   D   31.2
IOD     I   D   32
KK      K   WW  73
KK      K   WW  69.8
KK      K   WW  64.5
KK      K   WW  62.3
KK      K   D   57.3
KK      K   D   60.6
KK      K   D   63.1
KK      K   D   64.3
KB      K   WW  62.7
KB      K   WW  41.1
KB      K   WW  65.9
KB      K   WW  79.1
KB      K   D   56
KB      K   D   55.5
KB      K   D   47.5
KB      K   D   52.2
KI      K   WW  74.7
KI      K   WW  80.1
KI      K   WW  82.4
KI      K   WW  72.1
KI      K   D   67.4
KI      K   D   51.7
KI      K   D   63.3
KI      K   D   67
BB      B   WW  70
BB      B   WW  62.8
BB      B   WW  78
BB      B   WW  77.7
BB      B   D   48.7
BB      B   D   45.8
BB      B   D   51.3
BB      B   D   56.8
BI      B   WW  76.8
BI      B   WW  59.7
BI      B   WW  77.2
BI      B   WW  87.1
BI      B   D   49.4
BI      B   D   34
BI      B   D   63.1
BI      B   D   50.8
II      I   WW  42.4
II      I   WW  48.1
II      I   WW  56.8
II      I   WW  50.1
II      I   D   39.5
II      I   D   41
II      I   D   40.1
II      I   D   41.9
ODOD    OD  WW  0
ODOD    OD  WW  21.3
ODOD    OD  WW  37.6
ODOD    OD  WW  5.5
ODOD    OD  D   NA
ODOD    OD  D   25.6
ODOD    OD  D   14.9
ODOD    OD  D   22.6
KOD     OD  WW  NA
KOD     OD  WW  12
KOD     OD  WW  14.4
KOD     OD  WW  30
KOD     OD  D   NA
KOD     OD  D   8.5
KOD     OD  D   23
KOD     OD  D   27.3
BOD     OD  WW  15
BOD     OD  WW  35.9
BOD     OD  WW  26.9
BOD     OD  WW  24.5
BOD     OD  D   21.5
BOD     OD  D   11.6
BOD     OD  D   20
BOD     OD  D   18.2
IOD     OD  WW  33.9
IOD     OD  WW  20.4
IOD     OD  WW  NA
IOD     OD  WW  NA
IOD     OD  D   NA
IOD     OD  D   33.7
IOD     OD  D   31.3
IOD     OD  D   26.4
KK      K   WW  76.4
KK      K   WW  74.5
KK      K   WW  63.8
KK      K   WW  72
KK      K   D   65.8
KK      K   D   54
KK      K   D   56.5
KK      K   D   62
KB      B   WW  68.7
KB      B   WW  65.9
KB      B   WW  60.6
KB      B   WW  66.1
KB      B   D   53.8
KB      B   D   52.4
KB      B   D   49.3
KB      B   D   54.1
KI      I   WW  34.3
KI      I   WW  NA
KI      I   WW  37.2
KI      I   WW  50.3
KI      I   D   21
KI      I   D   34.4
KI      I   D   34.7
KI      I   D   18.4
BB      B   WW  42.5
BB      B   WW  54.4
BB      B   WW  74.3
BB      B   WW  71.4
BB      B   D   40.7
BB      B   D   45.7
BB      B   D   51.7
BB      B   D   39.4
BI      I   WW  46.4
BI      I   WW  41.9
BI      I   WW  29.9
BI      I   WW  29.6
BI      I   D   27.4
BI      I   D   36.5
BI      I   D   25
BI      I   D   36.6
II      I   WW  31.3
II      I   WW  51.2
II      I   WW  51.5
II      I   WW  41.6
II      I   D   38
II      I   D   35.6
II      I   D   40.5
II      I   D   33.5
```

I can perform the anova if I subset the data into separate frames e.g

```
statsOD<-subset(stats, plant=="OD")

aovOD<-aov(statsOD$height~stats$treatment)
```

Which works but I have a larger data set with many traits and it would be more efficient and neater  avoiding making lots of new data frames. Is there a way of building it into the anova below is an example of some code I have tried

```
aov1<-aov(stats$height~stats$treatment, plant=="OD")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset inside the `aov` like this:

```
aov1 <- aov(stats$height[stats$plant == "OD"] ~ stats$treatment[stats$plant == "OD"])
```

Or, to reduce the typing, you could use the `with` function:

```
aov1 <- with(stats, aov(height[plant == "OD"] ~ treatment[plant == "OD"]))
```

Comment: or `aov1 <- aov(height~treatment,data=stats,subset=(plant=="OD"))`

Comment: @BenBolker nice (+1), and even shorter!